# issue while using JNi (JAVA -> C)

Tags: c, java-native-interface

Am using java11 on mac

JNIExample.java

```
class JNIExample {

  // Native method, no body.
  public native void sayHello(int length);

  public static void main (String args[]) {
    String str = "Hello, world!";

    (new JNIExample()).sayHello(str.length());
  }

  // This loads the library at runtime. NOTICE: on *nix/Mac the extension of the
  // lib should exactly be `.jnilib`, not `.so`, and have `lib` prefix, i.e.
  // the library file should be `libjniexample.jnilib`.
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("jniexample");
  }
}
```

then i use javac -h . HelloWorldJNI.java this generates a HelloWorldJNI.h file in same folder which is as below.

JNIExample.h

```
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class JNIExample */

#ifndef _Included_JNIExample
#define _Included_JNIExample
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     JNIExample
 * Method:    sayHello
 * Signature: (I)V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JNIExample_sayHello
  (JNIEnv *, jobject, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

in this file #include <jni.h> its unable to find it, so i have edited this line toas below:

```
#include "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h"

#include "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin/jni_md.h"
```

Issue : now am not sure how to compile this.

if i proceed without compiling

gcc -I"$JAVA_HOME/include" -I"$JAVA_HOME/include/darwin/" -o libjniexample.dylib -shared JNIExample.c

error:

In file included from JNIExample.c:2:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.8.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h:45:10: fatal error: 'jni_md.h' file not found
#include "jni_md.h"
^~~~~~~~~~

Comment: What does `echo $JAVA_HOME` give?

Comment: jni_md.h not in $JAVA_HOME/include/darwin/? 
Please double check the whole path.

Comment: After a lot research what i found is jni.h & jni_md.h are can be modified in the JNIExample.h file. i did the same, now what happens is how do i compile my .headers file. Is it required to compile.?

without compile i proceded i was able to generate the object file for the same. but when i tried the final command to run the program: it says.  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:

full error added in below comment.

Comment: since am using the MAC os am making my lib as .dylib

error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libnative in java.library.path: [/Users/XXX/Desktop/xyz/new/libnative.dylib]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
at HelloWorldJNI.<clinit>(JNIExample.java:)

Comment: `java.library.path` should be the directory *containing* libnative.dylib, not the file itself.